# Access manager information from Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

[image]

Attach is the picture of active directory, which i got from my IT department. Now i want to get the manager information in C#.

NOTE: I am able to get all information of user but there isn't any key of manager, but IT department just gave me above attached screenshot. So can you please help from where i can get?

[image]

This is the information, which i am getting from below mentioned code.

```
public static UserPrincipal GetUser(string sUserName)
{
   PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = GetPrincipalContext();

   UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = 
       UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPrincipalContext, sUserName);
   return oUserPrincipal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
        var loginName = @"loginNameOfInterestedUser";
        var ldap = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://domain.something.com");
        var search = new DirectorySearcher(ldap)
        {
            Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + loginName + "))"
        };
        var result = search.FindOne();
        if (result == null)
            return;
        var fullQuery = result.Path;
        var user = new DirectoryEntry(fullQuery);
        DirectoryEntry manager;
        if (user.Properties.PropertyNames.OfType<string>().Contains("manager"))
        { 
            var managerPath = user.Properties["manager"].Value;
            manager = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + managerPath);
        }
```

Comment: there isn't any value for manager, i have updated the question kindly have a look.

Comment: @AwnAli what type `oUserPrincipal` has? It's not `DirectoryEntry`, thats why it doesn't have `manager` property. Try my solution

Comment: Your Code works but its giving me managerPath = "CN=manager name,OU=bac,DC=company,DC=com" which is correct.
 But exception on following line:
 manager = new DirectoryEntry(managerPath);

Comment: The value provided for adsObject does not implement IADs. this is the exception which i am getting on this line manager = new DirectoryEntry(managerPath);

Comment: manager = GetUser(managerPath.ToString()).GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
Above line of code is working fine but its too slow how i can mange to make it fast.

Comment: @AwnAli LDAP is slow. Get used to it :(. And by the way, `manager = new DirectoryEntry(managerPath)` could throw an error, cause it should be like this : `manager = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + managerPath);`

Answer (score 1):

Look at the attribute editor tab, this lists all attributes for the object.

The attribute does exist and it is called manager.

[image]

---

```
DirectoryEntry userEntry = new DirectoryEntry(“LDAP://developer.hamilton.com/CN=Mike Hamilton,DC=developer,DC=Hamilton,DC=com”, “<adminAccountName>”,”<adminPassword”);
```

Here you would replace adminAccountName and adminPassword with the actual credentials of any account that actually has permissions to perform the binding.

http://geekswithblogs.net/mhamilton/archive/2005/10/04/55920.aspx

Comment: there isn't any value for manager, i have updated the question kindly have a look.

Comment: i managed to get above string of manager i.e. "CN=manager name,OU=bac,DC=company,DC=com"
Can you please tell me how i can get the DirectoryEntry object of manager from above string? currently i am getting like this: manager = GetUser(managerPath.ToString()).GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry; but its too slow.